# Motherboard posts after electrical short but does not boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard

**Edit:** I'd like to note that in my post-mortem I found out that I had, indeed, plugged the jumper onto the wrong header. Ugh. Just because they're both *labeled* "HD Audio" doesn't mean that they should actually be plugged together... Ugh. -1 for not looking more closely at the manual. So, PEBKAC onthat one...

After switching PC hardware from one case to another I plugged headphones into the front audio jack. I believe this shorted something on the motherboard and shut down the system. The system now boots and I can access the bios but after the splash screen I only see a blinking white cursor in the upper left.

The system will not boot to CD despite being configured to do so in the bios.
The system can see all attached hardware (hard drives etc.) in the bios.
A CMOS reset (pulling the battery) did not resolve the problem.

The system appears to POST successfully but hangs after the splash screen.

The motherboard is an Intel DX58S0. The case is an Antec 900.

Anything that might bring it back to life would be greatly appreciated! I am tempted to believe that the motherboard is shot.

Comment: I'd unplug all the drives, and try booting with a known working liveusb at this point. What sort of splash screen? The intel one or the OS one?

Comment: Hey! The intel splash screen displays. I could set up a live USB with my laptop and try it... The bios recognizes all of my hard drives and optical drives as present. Odd that the bios would see them as attached but not boot from any of them. Also, the system will not boot from an OS disk in the optical drive.

Comment: Yeah, if nothing else, we can work out if it boots as all, and narrow down the issue somewhat. I'd also try the drives on another system to be sure.

Comment: I'll hammer out a live Ubuntu flash drive in the mornin. Too steamed with all this tonight. Just rebuilt the old system into the new case a week ago. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Is the speaker port on an internal header? (i.e. is it on the front panel connected by a cable to the motherboard?)

Comment: @davidw Yes it is. I am wondering if the new case connected to the old header (Mobo is approx 4.5 yrs old) caused the short.

Comment: Ok looks like a no-go on the LiveUSB. Unplugged all the other SATA devices, checked the boot order and plugged the flash drive directly into the motherboard. I'm wondering if an EEPROM or some other type of memory device on the mobo was flashed during the short and lost the boot instructions. I can access the BIOS settings no problem, but something else is preventing the PC from booting. Anyway to reflash the BIOS externally without special hardware? Looking like I need to rebuild this rig... Ugh.

Comment: Just reflashed the bios by "booting" to a built in bios update menu; Intel boards let you hold down F7 and choose a .bio file from attached media. The reflash went just fine but the system still will not load any form of bootable media.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting that header and seeing if it will boot?

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I did :P. I'm about 99% sure this thing is toast. Just ordered a new mobo, processor and RAM :P. Ah well! At least the rig was almost 5 yrs old. Hope the case doesn't do this to my new build!